# pip install netifaces in VS Code, issue with package mentioned above

Tags: python

pip3 install netifaces
Collecting netifaces
Using cached netifaces-0.11.0.tar.gz (30 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for netifaces, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: netifaces
Running setup.py install for netifaces ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for netifaces did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [5 lines of output]
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'netifaces' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> netifaces

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Comment: Hi Anookarsh. It's hard to follow what's going on in your question. Are you installing from command line? Or IDE (VS code)? Please reformat you code following guidelines from here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting